# Looking for non-destructive counterpart of `splice ARRAY,OFFSET,LENGTH,LIST`

Tags: perl

`splice` is "destructive"; i.e. it modifies its first argument "in place".

For example:

```
  DB<63> @a = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

  DB<64> @b = (20, 30, 40)

  DB<65> splice( @a, 2, 3, @b )

  DB<66> x \@a
0  ARRAY(0x1daf6e0)
   0  0
   1  1
   2  20
   3  30
   4  40
   5  5
```

(The `splice` expression above *returns* the elements spliced out, but in this question I'm interested only in `slice`'s side effects.)

---

**Q:** Is there a "non-destructive" counterpart **function** of `splice`?

E.g. if `@a` and `@b` are as *originally* defined above, then the desired `non_destructive_splice` function would be such that after

```
@new_a = non_destructive_splice( @a, 2, 3, @b );
```

...the variable `@new_a` would hold `(0, 1, 20, 30, 40, 5)`, and `@a` would be **left unchanged**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a copy:

```
my @new_a = @a;
splice( @new_a, 2, 3, @b );
```

Or if you want the same interface (incl negative offsets and optional arguments):

```
sub splice_r(\@;$$@) {
   my $num_args = @_;
   my $a      = shift;
   my $offset = shift;
   my $len    = shift;

   my @new_a = @$a;
   if    ($num_args == 1) { splice(@new_a)                    }
   elsif ($num_args == 2) { splice(@new_a, $offset)           }
   elsif ($num_args >= 3) { splice(@new_a, $offset, $len, @_) }
   return @new_a;
}

my @new_a = splice_r(@a, 2, 3, @b);
```

Or use a slice to avoid needless copying:

```
my @new_a = ( @a[0..1], @b, @a[5..$#a] );
```

Or if you want the same interface (incl negative offsets and optional arguments):

```
sub splice_r(\@;$$@) {
   my $num_args = @_;
   my $a   = shift;
   my $i   = shift;
   my $len = shift;

   $i //= 0;
   if ($i < 0) {
      $i += @$a;
      carp("Invalid argument") if $i < 0;
   }
   elsif ($i > @$a) {
      $i = @$a;
   }

   my $j;
   if ($num_args >= 3) {
      if ($len >= 0) {
         $j = $i + $len;
      } else {
         $j = @$a + $len;
         $j = 0 if $j < 0;
      }
   } else {
      $e = $#$a;
   }

   return ( @$a[0..$i-1], @_, @$a[$j..$#$a] );
}

my @new_a = splice_r(@a, 2, 3, @b);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@new_a = @a;
splice @new_a, 2, 3, @b;
```

Comment: that was adorable

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive version of splice. I call it slice:

```
sub slice {
  my ($offset, $len) = splice(@_, -2, 2);
  my $last = $offset + $len - 1;
  return @_[$offset..$last];
}
```

This:

```
my @array = qw(a b c d e f g h);
my @cut = slice(@arr, -1, 3); # Even works with wrap-around indexes.

print("@array\n");
print("@cut\n");
```

Results in:

```
a b c d e f g h
h a b
```